# How to split up a character in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a datafram containing a column: "AA", "BB", "AB"....

```
combination.a <- apply(combn(LETTERS[1:8],2),2,paste0,collapse="")
combination.b <- apply(combn(LETTERS[8:1],2),2,paste0,collapse="")
combination <- c(combination.a,combination.b)
```

and want to get two new columns "A" "B" "A"... & "A" "B" "B"...

How should I execute it?

Comment: This is quite unclear, check you show a proper initial input and expected output?

Comment: that said, check `strsplit(x, sep ="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate` and separate after the first position, though your data need to be in a data frame (`combination2`):

```
library(tidyr)
combination2 <- data.frame(combination)
combination2 %>% separate(combination, into = c("sep.1", "sep.2"), sep = 1)
```

output:

```
#    sep.1 sep.2
# 1      A     B
# 2      A     C
# 3      A     D
# 4      A     E
# 5      A     F
# 6      A     G
# 7      A     H
# 8      B     C
# 9      B     D
# 10     B     E
```

A base R approach would be to use `strsplit` and `do.call` with `rbind` on the original `combination`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(combination, split = ""))
```

Output

```
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "A"  "D" 
# [4,] "A"  "E" 
# [5,] "A"  "F" 
# [6,] "A"  "G" 
# [7,] "A"  "H" 
# [8,] "B"  "C" 
# [9,] "B"  "D" 
# [10,] "B"  "E"
```